# excel vba creating login screen

Tags: excel, forms, vba, authentication

and thanks in advance for helping. I am creating a log in screen for some workbooks Upon thisworkbook being open I have "userform1.show" and in the userform i have hardcoded a username and password. when the userform1 pops up asking for username and password I am able to click the X and it just closes the form and the user can still use the workbook. How do I have that X close the entire workbook. I don't know what that X is called in VB. I have tried "application.enablecancelkey" with all 3 options but none work.

A) is that the right way to go about it? 
B) if it is where do I put that?

Comment: Why not just password protect the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = 0 Then
        ThisWorkbook.Close
    End If
End If
```

Alternatively you could also prevent the Login Form being closed by the "**X**"

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    If CloseMode = 0 Then
        cancel = 1
        MsgBox "Please use cancel if you want to leave the Login Box.", _
            vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Please confirm ..."
    End If
End Sub
```

That's how we do it with our logins...

Comment: Thanks skofgar. This works good but upon loggin in I have to enable macros then my login box pops up. If I X out it closes the login but still prompts me to save (i guess once I accept macros it has officially captured something behind the scenes?). Anyway, if I cancel on the save box it allows me into the worksheet anyway. How do I stop that from happening?

Comment: The Login is used by our company to know, who is accessing the database by the Excel tool and who is uploading something to the database from it. To avoid the macro accept window you could digitally sign the Excel sheet with a signature you use on all your company computers.. however if Macro is turned off at first place the login will never come and anybody will be able to access the content.. File password protection (as chris neilsen already mentioned) is therefore the only solution I know

Answer (score 3):

You must set the QueryClose event up like this:

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
   If MsgBox("Exit?", vbOKCancel) = vbOK Then
      ThisWorkbook.Close
   Else
      Cancel = True
   End If
End Sub
```

Please, make the adjustments you think it's needed to better suit your real case.

Comment: The above code works on the X button but now is giving me the msgbox after I enter in a username and password and closes the workbook anyway. What am I missing? I have the exact code you have above

Comment: @bdubb - The code I posted was an example, as I already wrote you have to make the adjustments. Altough I'm pretty sure it's not hard to figure out what to do, to better guide you in the right direction, you must provide more of your source code.